# Transfer data from Excel sheet into SQL Server database

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

I have an Excel sheet that contains some data. I want to store that data into a SQL Server  database from that aspx page.

I am trying to store data but get error as below:

> *The Microsoft Office Access database engine cannot open or write to the file.
>   It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data.*

This is my code:

```
string excelConnectionString = @"provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source=" + path + ";extended properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;'";

//Create Connection to Excel work book
OleDbConnection excelConnection =new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);
//Create OleDbCommand to fetch data from Excel
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select [ID],[Name],[Designation] from [Sheet1$]",excelConnection);
excelConnection.Open();
OleDbDataReader dReader;
dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(strConnection);
//Give your Destination table name
sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "Excel_table";
sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader);
excelConnection.Close();
```

and thanks in advance ...

Comment: Can you  give the total description of error (stack trace)?

Comment: Stack Trace:


[OleDbException (0x80040e37): The Microsoft Office Access database engine could not find the object 'sheet1'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.]
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr) +1082864

Comment: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult) +247
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult) +194
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult) +58

Comment: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader() +6
filemanagement.WebForm2.btnSend_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\nxsol\Desktop\filemanagement\filemanagement\WebForm2.aspx.cs:34
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +118
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +112

Comment: System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5563

Comment: Try to keep the excel file in other drive than OS drive(C drive) and try.

Answer (score 0):

YOU NEED TO close the Access database database file than your code will access the data/.

Comment: or some resource might acess the database that is why your getting this issue please shut down ur pc next time try your luck

Answer (score 0):

Hi check the following things:

1.Access file which you are using should not be opened.

2.It should not be read only.

3.You should have read/write permission for folder where file that you want to access is placed.

Comment: thanks for quick replay , but i have permission of that file allready

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate user account (NETWORK SERVICE by default) needs MODIFY permissions on the folder that the Excel file sits in. Adds the permission to that folder in which Excel file present.